# Samba Windows ACLs How to set SeDiskOperatorPrivilege?

Tags: permissions, samba

I'm working with this tutorial: [Setting up a Share Using Windows ACLs](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_a_Share_Using_Windows_ACLs) and I am trying to set up Windows ACLs for a file share. The problem is that I am stuck on the step *granting the SeDiskOperatorPrivilege privilege*

```
root@nas01:~# net rpc rights grant "nas01\root" SeDiskOperatorPrivilege -U 
"workgroup\administrator"
Password for [WORKGROUP\administrator]:
Bad SMB2 (sign_algo_id=2) signature for message
[0000] 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ........ ........
[0000] 27 67 1D 5D E3 E8 D9 96   F3 79 93 12 8E 48 02 86   'g.].... .y...H..
Could not connect to server 127.0.0.1
Connection failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
root@nas01:~#
```

I have also tried

```
root@nas01:~# net rpc rights grant "nas01admin" SeDiskOperatorPrivilege -U "workgroup\nas01admin"
Password for [WORKGROUP\nas01admin]:
Failed to grant privileges for nas01admin (NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED)
root@nas01:~#
```

Note that in my case, the share already exists and works, whereas in the the tutorial you set the SeDiskOperatorPrivilege first, and then create the share. I can connect to the share from my Windows computer using 'nas01admin' and the SMB password that I set. As suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1092958/samba-net-rpc-rights-grant-sediskoperatorprivilege-fails) I have set a user map in /etc/samba/smb.conf

```
[global]  
username map = /etc/samba/user.map
```

my /etc/samba/user.map file

```
!root = WORKGROUP\administrator WORKGROUP\Administrator
```

Unfortunately, all the turorials out there that I found, are written for Samba either being an AD domain controller or Samba being an AD member. In my case however, there is no domain, no Active Directory. It is just a standalone server. This is a supported configuration according to the documentation.

The users and groups on my system:

```
root@nas01:~# users
nas01admin nas01admin
root@nas01:~# groups
root
root@nas01:~#
```

My share looks like this. Everything else in the smb.conf is at default settings, except for the user map (see above)

```
[sambashare]
    comment = Samba on Ubuntu
    path = /test/share1
    read only = no
    browsable = yes
```

Comment: You appear to be running a workgroup (or rather two: WORKGROUP and NAS01) and as such you have users on one computer and totally different users on the other, even if they have the same usernames. You also shouldn't have to give root the privilege, you have mapped administrator to root, so it should work without the privilege as long as you do it as Administrator.

Comment: What should I do? Is the user mapping not right? The user that is used is nas01admin and it is a workgroup. No domain.

Comment: Either stop trying to do domain like things in a workgroup or set up a domain.