# Samba net rpc rights grant SeDiskOperatorPrivilege: NT_STATUS_INVALID_TOKEN

Tags: server, permissions, samba, 22.04, kerberos

I've just installed Ubuntu Server 22.04 and joining it to an existing AD as a member server. I'm following this howto: https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_a_Share_Using_Windows_ACLs

Everything's working fine until I get to

```
net rpc rights grant "SAMDOM\Unix Admins" SeDiskOperatorPrivilege -U "SAMDOM\administrator"
```

which fails as follows:

```
net rpc rights grant "DOMAIN\Unix Admins" SeDiskOperatorPrivilege -U "DOMAIN\administrator"
Password for [DOMAIN\administrator]:
Could not connect to server 127.0.0.1
Connection failed: NT_STATUS_INVALID_TOKEN
```

I found this solved question from three years ago which seemed to be the same issue, but that solution didn't make any difference (I already had the user.map file): [Samba net rpc rights grant SeDiskOperatorPrivilege Fails](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1092958/samba-net-rpc-rights-grant-sediskoperatorprivilege-fails)

member server smb.conf:

```
# Global parameters
[global]
    log file = /var/log/samba/%m.log
    log level = 1
    max log size = 1000
    realm = DOMAIN.TLD
    security = ADS
    server role = member server
    username map = /etc/samba/user.map
    workgroup = DOMAIN
    idmap config * : range = 10000-9999999
    idmap config * : backend = autorid
    map acl inherit = Yes
    vfs objects = acl_xattr
```

krb5.conf:

```
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = DOMAIN.TLD
    dns_lookup_realm = false
    dns_lookup_kdc = true
```

user.map:

```
!root = DOMAIN\Administrator DOMAIN\administrator
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, add 'min domain uid = 0' to /etc/samba/smb.conf and reload the config or restart Samba.

Comment: That fixed it! I understand why now, but so annoying to spend so much time on something so little. Thank you!